# How to get the dbms.output value returned by a PL-SQL block in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, database, dbms-output

I am trying to execute a PL-SQL block in c# using `System.Data.OrcaleClient`.
The PL-SQL block when executed in oracle, prints the result using `dbms.ouput`.

I want to get that "`dbms.ouput`" result in my C# code.

Please help.

Comment: Why don't you turn you block into a [function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php) and _return_ the result?

Comment: Hi Ben, we are integrating with a third party and they have provided us with the PL-SQL block, to get the required result

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `get_line` function of `dbms_output` package. You can create a procedure to return the output. Something like this (just a example):

```
procedure call_with_output(p_output out varchar2) is
  vret integer := 0;
  vtxt varchar2(4000);
begin
  dbms_output.enable;
  -- here call code that generate lines
  -- use the loop to retrieve info
  while vret = 0 loop
    dbms_output.get_line(vtxt, vret);
    if vret = 0 then
      if p_output  is null then
        p_output := vtxt;
      else
       p_output := p_output || chr(10) || vtxt;
      end if;
    end if;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.disable;
end;
```

Comment: I like your solution.  It combines the simplicity of using `get_line` (instead of `get_lines`) with a single call to the server.  The answer I was working on involved calling `get_lines` via ODP.NET, which is a ridiculous faff. +1

Comment: +1  Note, however, that this will only work if the total amount of output is 32k or less.  That's probably the case but you can get a decent amount of debug output get written to `dbms_output` if you're generating it in a loop.

Comment: To get 32K, the declaration of vtxt must be changed to `vtxt varcahr2(32767)`

Comment: @Sérgio Michels - Thats a nice solution but the data returned by the pl-sql block is huge.So since there is a size limit in using get_line,I think it wouldnt work :(

Comment: @Dinu Try modify the example to insert in a temporary table, instead of return as out of the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the next method:

```
    private string GetDbmsOutputLine()
    {
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand
        {
            Connection = <connection>,
            CommandText = "begin dbms_output.get_line(:line, :status); end;",
            CommandType = CommandType.Text
        };

        OracleParameter lineParameter = new OracleParameter("line",  
            OracleType.VarChar);
        lineParameter.Size = 32000;
        lineParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add(lineParameter);

        OracleParameter statusParameter = new OracleParameter("status",  
            OracleType.Int32);
        statusParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add(statusParameter);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (command.Parameters["line"].Value is DBNull)
            return null;

        string line = command.Parameters["line"].Value as string;

        return line;
    }
```

Call it several times to get multistring value because there are problems with calling dbms_output.get_lines with System.Data.OracleClient.