PL/SQL output using VC#
How can I get the output of my PL/SQL query into my code using the OracleDataReader
I have turned serveroutput on
and tried to read the output as so
But it always says no output
ConnectDB();
OracleCommand command1 = conn.CreateCommand();
command1.CommandText = "begin dbms_output.put_line('Output'); end;";
command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleDataReader dr = command1.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
    while(dr.Read())
    {
    string str = dr[0].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("No output");
conn.Close();


I don't think that counts as "output records". Try SELECT 1 FROM dual; as CommandText

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545389/how-to-get-the-dbms-output-value-returned-by-a-pl-sql-block-in-c-sharp

My C# is rusty, but in general for any Oracle client if you want in a client to manually consume the dbms_output queue that put_line populates you'll need to call dbms_output.get_line or dbms_output.get_lines and bind the out vars to a client variable. put_line stuffs lines into the queue (it writes, it doesn't read). It's up to the client to ask for those lines using get_line. If this was just a test and you don't actually need dbms_output, don't use it here - run a query or bind the return value of a function - anything that actually returns something. put_line doesn't.

You can try perform a query, e.g.
using OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

// Typical Oracle feature - query Dual table to read a constant
command.CommandText = 
  @"select 'Output'
      from Dual";

using reader = command.ExecureReader();

if (reader.Read()) 
    // Let me show general case, when we don't know field type
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(reader[0]));
else
    MessageBox.Show("No output");

